# Match specific letter in any language

Tags: javascript, regex

I've been searching for an answer to this question for almost an hour now, so I thought I would finally ask. I know you can use `\p{L}` to match any kind of letter from any language, but I haven't encountered any way to match a letter from any language that is the equivalent of some English letter, like the letter a.

For example, ideally I'd want to match any equivalent of "a" or "A" in any language (like: Å, å, Ǻ, ǻ, Ḁ, ḁ, ẚ, Ă, etc...)

Comment: Is **Æ** equivalent to A?

Comment: `str.normalize("NFD").replace(/\p{Diacritic}/gu, "")`

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues Looks like that somewhat works, I was hoping for something that yielded better results with most - if not all unicode characters that could be associated with an English version. That being said, I wasn't sure if this was very plausible in the first place.

Comment: The only real exception that I am aware of with this method is for things like `ẚ` (_LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH RIGHT HALF RING_). The reason? Its compatibility decomposition uses **U+02BE** `ʾ` _MODIFIER LETTER RIGHT HALF RING_, which is outside the range of **U+0300**- **U+036F** that `p{Diacritic}` uses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best shot is something like:

```
myStr.normalize("NFD").replace(/\p{Diacritic}/gu, "")
```

It uses [`normalize()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize), and needs ES6. For example:

```
myStr = "ÁàÀăĂắẮâÂåÅǻǺäÄãÃąĄāĀȃȂḁḀćčçÇéÉèÈêÊěëËḝęēĒȇȆíÍìÌîÎïÏīĪȋȊľńñÑóÓòÒôÔöÖõÕōŌȏȎŘȓȒśšŠşŞșȘţŢțȚúÚùÙûÛůŮüÜűũŨūŪȗȖẘýÝẙÿŸȳȲźžŽż"
myStr.normalize("NFD").replace(/\p{Diacritic}/gu, "")
// "AaAaAaAaAaAaAaAaAaAaAaAaAcccCeEeEeEeeEeeeEeEiIiIiIiIiIiIlnnNoOoOoOoOoOoOoORrRssSsSsStTtTuUuUuUuUuUuuUuUuUwyYyyYyYzzZz"
```

It works even for accented non-latin letters like `"ᾰᾸӑӐёӂӁйЙ"` and weirder things, like many letters sharing accent `b͝g`.

On what it does not work? Well, for things like `ẚ` (`LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH RIGHT HALF RING`).

The reason? Its compatibility decomposition uses **U+02BE** `ʾ` (`MODIFIER LETTER RIGHT HALF RING`), which is outside the range of **U+0300**-**U+036F** that `p{Diacritic}` uses. (Check [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_%28diacritic%29) for reference)